# Algorithm is linear (O(n)) to size of input, but what if input size is exponential

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

The instructor said that the complexity of an algorithm is typically measured with respect to its input size.

So, when we say an algorithm is linear, then even if you give it an input size of 2^n (say 2^n being the number of nodes in a binary tree), the algorithm is still linear to the input size?

The above seems to be what the instructor means, but I’m having a hard time turning it in my head. If you give it a 2^n input, which is exponential to some parameter ‘n’, but then call this input “x”, then, sure, your algorithm is linear to x. But deep-down, isn’t it still exponential in ‘n’?  What’s the point of saying its linear to x?

Comment: Since you were the one to propose calling the input `x`, it would seem to be incumbent on you to justify doing so.

Comment: ```32 = 2^5```, and ```32=4*8```. One statement doesn't make the other one false. However, one expresses 32 as an exponent and the other one as a linear multiplication.

Comment: Define it however you want, but the fact remains if you are running a typical traversal on a binary tree, each node is visited once. As such, it seems misguided to think of the algorithm as being anything but linear "deep down".

Comment: Here is the quick and dirty idea - linear algorithm grows processing time linearly. Or close enough to linear. So, let's say processing `n=1` takes 2ms. With `n=10` it takes 20ms. With `n=100` it takes 200ms. So, even if you give it an input which is `2^10` or `1024` - a linear relation means it should take 2048ms to finish. "*if you give it a 2^n input*" - that's not really what `n` measures. Your "exponential" input is just expressed as `n=2^x`, it's not `2^n`. `n` is the size of the input, not what you modify the input size with.

Comment: @ggorlen yes, you’ve hit my point of confusion. The complexity of a traversal on a binary tree is ‘linear’ to the number of nodes, but then the # of nodes is exponential (say, to depth). In my case, each depth is a decision-variable, so it is exponential to the number ‘n’ of decision variables ...

Comment: @puf the number of nodes is not "exponential". The number of nodes is whatever the number of nodes is. We do not define "how fast `n` rises" for you to make a claim like this. To determine the complexity of the algorithm we *only* look at how it behaves with relation to the input. How or even *if* the input can only be expressed in specific numbers (as opposed to any number) is irrelevant. Also, it's very rarely the case.

Comment: @VLAZ ah, ok, I am starting to get it now. that helps a lot. thanks :)

Comment: Being able to decompose a problem is useful.  If we know that the base algorithm is linear but the input size is exponential, that gives us more information than just declaring the overall process to be exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see the term "linear," you should ask - linear *in what*? Usually, when we talk about an algorithm's runtime being "linear time," we mean "the algorithm's runtime is O(n), where n is the size of the input."

You're asking what happens if, say, n = 2<sup>k</sup> and we're passing in an exponentially-sized input into the function. In that case, since the runtime is O(n) and n = 2<sup>k</sup>, then the overall runtime would be O(2<sup>k</sup>). There's no contradiction here between this statement and the fact that the algorithm runs in linear time, since "linear time" means "linear as a function of the size of the input."

Notice that I'm explicitly choosing to use a different variable k in the expression 2<sup>k</sup> to call attention to the fact that there are indeed two different quantities here - the size of the input as a function of k (which is 2<sup>k</sup>) and the variable n representing the size of the input to the function more generally. You sometimes see this combined, as in "if the runtime of the algorithm is O(n), then running the algorithm on an input of size 2<sup>n</sup> takes time O(2<sup>n</sup>)." That statement is true but a bit tricky to parse, since n is playing two different roles there.

Answer (score 2):

If an algorithm has a linear time-complexity, then it is linear regardless the size of the input. Whether it is a fixed size input, quadratic or exponential.

Obviously running that algorithm on a fixed size array, quadratic or exponential will take different time, but still, the complexity is `O(n)`.

---

Perhaps this example will help you understand, does running merge-sort on an array of size 16 mean merge-sort is `O(1)` because it took constant operations to sort that array? the answer is NO.

Comment: `running that algorithm on a fixed size array, quadratic or exponential will take different time` - this statement doesn't make sense. If an array has size 16, the size is fixed, quadratic (4^2) and exponential (2^4).

Answer (score 1):

When we say an algorithm is `O(n)`, means if the input size is `n`, it is linear regards to the input size. Hence, if `n` is exponential in terms of another parameter `k` (for example `n = 2^k`), the algorithm is linear as well, in regards to the input size.

Another example is time complexity for the binary search for an input array with size `n`. We say that binary search for a sorted array with size `n` is in `O(log(n))`. It means in regards to the input size, it takes asymptotically at most `log(n)` comparison to search an item inside an input array with size `n`,

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are printing first n numbers, and to print each number it takes 3 operations:

n-> 10, number of operations -> 3 x 10 = 30

n-> 100, number of operations -> 3 x 100 = 300

n-> 1000, number of operations -> 3 x 1000 = 3000

n ->10000, we can also say, n = 100^2 (say k^2),
number of operations  --> 3 x 10000 = 30,000
Even though n is exponent of something(in this case 100), our number of operations solely depends upon number on the input(n which is 10,000).

So we can say, it is linear time complexity algorithm.